# JavaScript screen.height and screen.width returns incorrect values

Tags: javascript, height, width, screen

I want to get screen resolution of user display from JS,
so i decide to use screen.height and screen.width properties, but i noticed that i got some incorrect values, f.e. i have full hd display with 1280 pixels in height but screen.height returns 630, and width 1120. What can cause that?
Thanks!

Edit: it seems it happens on FireFox for me, from IE 10 i got correct values.

Comment: Is this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/how-to-get-web-page-size-browser-window-size-screen-size-in-a-cross-browser-wa ? Do you get consistent results using the jQuery library?

Comment: Hm.. i found that this issue happens when i use Zoom, so when i reset zoom to default then FireFox returns correct values.

Answer (score 8):

Firefox returns a value based on the zoom percentage; however the window.devicePixelRatio gives you this percentage. Therefore the following JS code gives the correct values:

```
var w = screen.width; var h = screen.height;
var DPR = window.devicePixelRatio;
w = Math.round(DPR * w);
h = Math.round(DPR * h);
```

Comment: I think this show the max possible resolution, not the current one